# How can I only download the individuals that I have created in Protégé?

Tags: sparql, ontology, protege, linked-data

I like to download the individuals that I have created in Protégé and upload them in GraphDB as a file. When I downloaded the whole ontology, I saw that the individuals were also downloaded in the XML/RDF file. But is there a way to only download the individuals?

Comment: You should rephrase your question to "how to extract/export the instance data" out of your ontology. An individual itself won't exist in an RDF triple store like GraphDB given that the smallest unit of existence would be an RDF triple. So you want to export all OWL axioms about OWL individuals.

Answer (score 1):

if you're using the desktop version there's an option in the 'tools' menu to 'export to CSV' the dialog box has two windows the top window is named 'Entities to export'. You can shift select and pick the individuals.

[image]

[image]

here's the .csv it produces

[image]

Comment: while your answer is technically correct, it would be useless as one requirement is *"upload them in GraphDB"* - that's not gonna work with a simple CSV with a single column as GraphDB usually expects RDF triples. What the TO most likely is asking for is how to get just the statement (aka OWL axioms) about the individuals, i.e. the instance data. An RDF node never exists with being involved in an RDF triple.